# Как сделать так, чтобы события jquery кода навешивались на элементы только после того, как все данные на стороне сервера подгрузятся?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

У меня есть jQuery код такого типа

```
function init() {
    initRelatedGoodsCarousel();
    tags();
..........
};

function initRelatedGoodsCarousel() {
        $('.owl-related').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            nav:true,
            dots:false,
            responsiveClass:true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:2
                },
                600:{
                    items:4
                },
                1000:{
                    items:6,
                    margin:0,
                    autoplay:true,
                    autoplayTimeout:80000,
                }
            }
        });
}

function tags() {
    $('#list_tags li').each(function(){
        posDiv($(this));
        randomSize($(this));
    });
    $('.wrap_search_tag').hover(function(){
            $('#list_tags li').each(function(){
                animateDiv($(this));
            });
        },
        function(){
            $('#list_tags li').stop();
        });
........
}
```

Для того, чтобы он срабатывал после того, как vue js построит DOM я в нужном мне компоненте использовала такой скрипт

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    import callApi from '~/libraries/api.js'
    export default {
        name: 'Tags',
        data () {
            return {
                tags: []
            }
        },
        updated() {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    init();
                }, 1000)
            })
        },
        created: function () {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                callApi('tags', '', '').then((res) => {
                    this.tags = res.data.data;
                });
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

то есть в `updated()` вызывала функцию `init()` из jQuery кода, а данные с REST API я подгружала с помощью `callApi()` в `created`.

Однако такой подход срабатывает не каждый раз. Если страница чуть быстрее/медленнее загрузилась, то события из jQuery кода не успевали навешиваться. Пришлось даже с помощью `setTimeout()`замедлять функцию `init()`, но это также не каждый раз срабатывало. 
Также пробовала данные с API загружать с помощью `Vuex store`, но это также не срабатывает постоянно.

Быть может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Буду очень благодарна.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('ready',function() {
    //Выполниться сразу после загрузки DOM не дожидаясь "остального"
});

//Краткая запись
$(function(){
    //Выполниться сразу после загрузки DOM не дожидаясь "остального"
});

$(window).load(function() {
    //Выполниться после загрузки всего документа
});

//Pure js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    //Выполниться сразу после загрузки DOM не дожидаясь "остального"
}, false);

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    //Выполниться после загрузки всего документа
}, false );

//И прочие альтернативы pure js
window.attachEvent("onload", function(){
    //Выполниться после загрузки всего документа
});
document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
    //Выполниться после загрузки всего документа
});
```

Comment: Я так делала, но тогда события вообще не навешиваются или навешиваюся, но через раз

Comment: Спасибо, попробовала
`
$(window).load(function() {
    //Выполниться после загрузки всего документа
});
`
вроде бы пока работает